# Use SHA-512 and salt to hash an MD5 hashed password?

Tags: java, security, hash, sha

I am working on a system that has been hashing user passwords with MD5 (no salt). I want to store the passwords more securely using SHA-512 and a salt.

While this is easy enough to implement for future passwords, I'd like to also retrofit the existing MD5 hashed passwords, preferably without forcing all the users to change their passwords. My idea is to just use SHA-512 and and an appropriate salt to hash the existing MD5 hash. I can either then set some flag in the database that indicates which passwords were hashed from plain text, and which ones were hashed from an MD5 hash. Or I could just try both when authenticating users. Or even just hash new passwords with MD5 and then SHA-512/salt, so they can be treated the same as old passwords.

Programmatically, I don't think this will be a problem, but I don't know enough about encryption/hashing to know if I'm compromising the quality of the hash in any way by applying a SHA-512/salt hash to a password that was already MD5 hashed. My first instinct is that if anything, it would be even stronger, a very light key stretching.

My second instinct is that I don't really know what I'm talking about, so I'd better get advice. Any thoughts?

Comment: SHA-512 will offer very little improvement over MD5 (eg: `MD5(salt + password)` is practically equivalent to `SHA512(salt + password)`). General purpose hashing functions like MD5 and the SHA family were **not** built to store passwords. Use bcrypt.

Comment: Very true. I actually intended to do key stretching, but didn't make that clear in my question. I ended up using PBKDF2 instead of naively implementing my own key-stretching algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function composition with cryptographic primitives is dangerous and should not be done if avoidable. The common solution for your type of problem is to keep both hashes for a migration period, using the new hash where possible and transparently upgrading old passwords (when you check a password and it matches, rehash it with the new algorithm and store it)

This won't work if you have a challenge-response based scheme where you don't get to see the plaintext password, but since you seem to have a stored salt that does not change, I assume your application does the hashing.

Comment: This is a great answer. I'm implemented exactly this type of solution before and it's a great way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on transparently rehashing when the user logs in! Do you have any links that explain why applying a SHA-512 hash to a MD5-hashed value is less safe than applying a SHA-512 hash to a plain-text password? I'm interested to know why...

Comment: @JeremiahOrr: For your specific application, proper usage of a long enough unpredictable salt will do much more in terms of security than changing the hashing scheme. As j13r explained, applying SHA onto MD5 will not broaden the space of possible hashes, since they are constrained by the possible results of MD5. Also, using a one-way function specifically optimized for passwords would be even better, for example [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2).

Comment: @JeremiahOrr: Consider this exaggerated example. Suppose I define a hash function that maps any input m into either 0 or 1. As you might imagine, this is not a cryptographically secure hash function since the output space is so small. Now applying SHA-256 to the output of this hash function does not help (the output will either be SHA(0) or SHA(1)) because the output of the SHA-256 hash is limited by the output range of the first hash function.

Comment: @JaredNg I very much doubt that there are more passwords than MD5 hashes, even considering every password used by every single person on Earth.

Comment: @NullUserException In all likelihood you're correct, but the point of the example was to demonstrate that hashing the output of a hash function does not increase security.

Answer (score 4):

If you hash with MD5 first, you will only have the spread of MD5 (128 bit). A large fraction of the space of SHA512 will not be covered by your passwords. So you don't take advantage of SHA512, but it won't be worse than MD5.

You have the benefit that if someone obtains the SHA512 hash and doesn't know the salt (this you have to enforce somehow) can't look up the hashes and get the passwords -- something that would be possible with the MD5 database you have now.

So yes, you can just rehash the existing MD5 passwords. But as explained in the first paragraph, it would be a bad idea to apply MD5 to all new passwords as well and then hash them as SH512. A easy implementation would be to have a boolean 'salted' field in the database next to the hashes (but don't put the salt there).

Comment: `but don't put the salt there` - the whole point of a salt is that it doesn't have to be kept secret and can just be put plaintext next to the hashed values (you have a unique hash per password!). Also: Is that "hashing a MD5 password with SHA-512 won't do any harm" based on any actual facts or just some intuition? Because in general applying several hashes in sequence can do more harm than good..

Comment: The point of a hash function is that it provides a unique mapping between a variable size string and a number of n bits. Any good hash function avoids collisions, and in fact it is extremely hard to produce collisions on SHA-512 and even MD5 (unless you have arbitrary length, which you don't in passwords). Mapping a 128 bit value into a 512 bit space is trivial to do (you have 2^(512-128) unused values).  Collisions (which is the harm) are extremely unlikely to occur (probability 2^(128-512)).

Answer (score 1):

Trust your second instinct. Use an existing library made especially for hashing passwords instead of trying to cook up your own.

Probably hash your new passwords with MD5 and then hash the MD5 with your password hashing library. That way, you can maintain backwards compatibility with your old passwords.

I.e. password_hash(All old, md5'd passwords) and password_hash( md5(New passwords) )

(Warning: I'm not a cryptography expert)

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html

Comment: Oh, I don't intend to cook up my own hashing library, I just need to know what to do with the existing MD5-hashed passwords!

Comment: I'm no cryptography expert but I'd just run a password hashing function on the existing MD5 passwords. For new passwords, you would first do the old MD5 algorithm, then feed it to a proper password hashing function.
That, or you can somehow mark whether the password is using the old or new algorithm in the database (or whereever you're storing it).

Comment: @tangrs His original passwords are also MD5 hashed, it is already secured. He want to switch to SHA-512 with salt which is more secure. Why in the would would you suggest to him double hashing? That still would not solve the issue of how to tell the difference between new and old password. And to double hash is security through obscurity, which is just as good as no security, because no one know what the hell is going on and how to maintain it.

Comment: I meant double hashing as a way for backwards compatibility. (Admittedly, it does seem cheap and lazy)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at how most Bank and high security people does there password changing. Most of them basically ask people who is using the old encryption method to create a new password. I think you first solution of placing a flag on all existing old MD5 password users, and notify them they need to create new password and slowly migrate them to the new system. That way when you trouble shoot the system if anything goes wrong you won't be asking is this a new user or an old one. Are we double hashing or single? Should never compare two hash as a possible answer because what if MD5('abc') => 123, SHA('NO') => 123, that means someone could have typed in the wrong password but still gets in.