# Legacy app with md5 hashes: how to add salt and SHA1?

Tags: hash, md5, salt, sha

I've a legacy app where passwords are hashed using MD5 without salt. I'd like to switch to SHA1 with salt, but I'd like to keep current users' passwords.

My plan is to change hashing function to `sha1(md5(password) + salt)`. I'll be able to batch process all existing hashes using `sha1(<existing_pass> + salt)`.

1. Is it safe to keep md5 in this case?
2. Is it ok to have one single salt for all users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's not a good idea to keep md5, read this question: [Use SHA-512 and salt to hash an MD5 hashed password?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10028308/1073063).
2. It's better to have one salt for each user. With the same salt, users with the same password will have the same hash, and a rainbow table can be created for all your passwords at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

- As for question 1 I'm not quite sure but it seems to be OK.
- For question 2: It is never OK to have same salt for all users. Salt has two functions. To prevent using pre-generated hashes / rainbow tables to search leaked database, and to prevent generation of dictionary-based hashes and searching databases with them too. Common salt will work in first case making rainbow tables unusable, but won't prevent cracker from dictionary attack. If cracker knows the global salt, he can generate frequent passwords, hash them and grep entire database. If salt is generated per user this scenario isn't possible.

Comment: Thanks, any tips how to implement different salt for all users? Use some existing information, like id in the DB?

Comment: You can add dedicated field to User entity in database containing nice, random-generated salt. If for some reason You can't do it than user id will be ok. Definitely much better than common salt, or no salt at all