# Different md5 hash for same string in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, md5

I'm currently working on a swift application based on a particular API of a website. I use the md5 function to create valid url and access some JSON data which I can bring in my application with SwiftJSON.

I worked fine for the 6 first url but then I got an error in the checksum of my url. I checked it out and realize my md5 function in swift got the wrong hash

In my swift program, the hash of the string "answerfr1%3D%3DQf7AjOptTN6k2OyoTa7QjOptDM6k2OzoTa7cjOptjM6k2O1oTa7EjOptDMxoTa7AjOptnO2oTY" 
Give me this "09938c1325c87ef89251f668a8cf5d42"
But it's not correct because my link isn't valid

But by doing it myself with http://www.md5.cz/
I have this for result "9d78b73d28f590beb8ef25b5e4b99a1d" and my link works perfectly.

I don't know why my md5 function have no issues with the 6 first hash but give me a wrong hash for the 7.

And I realize www.md5.fr give me the same wrong code. Why is there different md5 hash for the same strings ?

My md5 function in swift :
[How to convert string to MD5 hash using ios swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163848/how-to-convert-string-to-md5-hash-using-ios-swift)

Hope you guys understand my issues here!
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: the thing you have get in swift program may be a NSData(I am not quite sure), try to convert it to string and print it again. let convertString = NSString(data: yourData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

Comment: You have to decode the percent escapes "%3D%3D" to "==".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Martin R, you solved my problem
"%3D" is equal to "="
so "%3D%3D" is equal to "=="