# Swift 2.2 MD5 hash from string

Tags: ios, hash, swift2, md5

i have been looking at the following (I am pretty new to IOS so any help would be gratefully appreciated).

[How to convert string to MD5 hash using ios swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163848/how-to-convert-string-to-md5-hash-using-ios-swift/37472379#37472379?newreg=2dce0d23db124fedb6dc38b73364fbfd)

And with the explanation of code used for Swift 2.2 from Hugo Alonso i am having problems actually using the function and declaring a string that is then hashed.

Code is below

```
struct MD5Digester {
// return MD5 digest of string provided
static func digest(string: String) -> String? {

    guard let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) else { return nil }

    var digest = [UInt8](count: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)

    CC_MD5(data.bytes, CC_LONG(data.length), &digest)

    return (0..<Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH)).reduce("") { $0 + String(format: "%02x", digest[$1]) }
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what specific kind of problem are your having?

Comment: Do you expect us to play detective to figure out what **your** problem is, or are you gonna tell us?

Comment: sorry guys, thought i was being clear enough. 

So the above works however in that i don't get any build errors however i don't know how to use so that i supply a STRING which is then HASHED using the above code

Comment: You need to use `let md5string = MD5Digester.digest(@"string that you want to convert to MD5")` and in md5string you have your result?

Comment: Hey Reiner Melian now you have pointed it out its so obvious.

Really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Of course MD5 is not secure and should not be used in new code.