# Marvel api returns That hash, timestamp and key combination is invalid swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using this solution to convert to md5 hash https://stackoverflow.com/a/32166735/1898829

and this is the code that I create the hash parameter I send to marvel.

```
class CharacterListInteractorApi: CharacterListInteractor {

    // MARK: Dependencies
    private let client: NetworkLayer

    // MARK: - Properties

    var timeStamp: String = ""

    // MARK: - Life cycle

    init(client: NetworkLayer) {
        self.client = client
    }

    // MARK: - Internal

    func verifySomething(someInput: String) -> Observable<Async<Any>> {
        timeStamp = Date().stringValue()
        return RxAlamofire
            .requestJSON(
                .get,
                 url,
                 parameters: parameters
            )
            .flatMap { (response, json) -> Observable<Any> in
                Observable.just(json)
            }.async()
    }
}

private extension CharacterListInteractorApi {
    var url: String {
        "https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters?apikey=ApiKey"
    }


    var hash: String { timeStamp+"privateKey"+"fbb2d7f9074949c9fb335f9a42e48678"
    }

    var md5Hash: Data {
        MD5(string: hash)
    }

    var parameters: [String: Any] {
        [
            "ts": timeStamp,
            "hash": md5Hash
        ]
    }
}
```

but I get an error from marvel saying That hash, timestamp and key combination is invalid

**update**

here is the date time func

```
   func stringValue() -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSSSSS'Z'"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
```

here is the print out of the md5 hash

```
(lldb) po md5Hash
▿ 16 bytes
  - count : 16
  ▿ pointer : 0x0000600003941c20
    - pointerValue : 105553176304672
  ▿ bytes : 16 elements
    - 0 : 188
    - 1 : 255
    - 2 : 118
    - 3 : 230
    - 4 : 64
    - 5 : 100
    - 6 : 140
    - 7 : 75
    - 8 : 144
    - 9 : 42
    - 10 : 18
    - 11 : 136
    - 12 : 94
    - 13 : 27
    - 14 : 230
    - 15 : 252
```

Comment: timeStamp = Date().stringValue() will return you time since 1970 ?

Comment: @AbuUlHassan Ive included the stringValue method

Comment: I personally think it will be timIntervalSince1970  based timeStamp not formatted date string.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan they mention in the documentation ts - a timestamp (or other long string which can change on a request-by-request basis) so I'm pretty sure its not that.

Comment: I added a printout from my has which in bytes not hex decimal which I suspect is the problem.

Comment: Of course your MD5 is not valid

Comment: convet like below ... 

func hash(name:String, string:String) -> Data? {
    let data = string.data(using:.utf8)!
    return hash(name:name, data:data)
}
let hashMD5 = hash(name:"MD5", data:yourString)

Comment: Also go there and check in example request 
time stamp is in since1970 format not dateFormatted in string

https://codingricky.com/post/swiftly-access-marvel-characters/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing this

```
var md5: String {
    let data = self.data(using: .utf8)
    var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH))

    _ = data!.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) in
        return CC_MD5(bytes.baseAddress, CC_LONG(data!.count), &digest)
    }

    return digest.reduce(into: "") { $0 += String(format: "%02x", $1) }
}
```